# Any good text editors with syntax highlighting for android?

Tags: android, web-development

I have a Sony Xperia Tipo device running 4.0.4 ICS. I'm looking for an app similiar to Notepad++ (with syntax highlighting) that I could use to develop my website. (PHP, JavaScript, HTML & CSS)

Paid & free are both welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime Text 2 is arguably the best editor for that level of web development.

Download: http://www.sublimetext.com/2

Free video tutorials: http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/perfect-workflow-in-sublime-text-free-course/

Comment: It seems to be iOS, Windows and Linux only, I don't see android version there.

Comment: If that's the case, then the 920 Text Editor is probably what you're looking for. 

http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/2012050503591090/920TextEditor.html